# Is it possible to create jquery draggable - droppable without clone?

Tags: jquery

I want to create something similar to this.

https://jsfiddle.net/79e4guqv/

```
<body>
 
<div id="droppable">Drop here</div>
<div id="draggable">Drag me</div>
 
<script>
$( "#draggable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).draggable();
$( "#droppable" ).droppable({
  drop: function() {
    $( "#droppable" ).appendChild($( "#draggable" ));
  }
});

</script>
```

The thing is I don't think it's a good idea for me to use clone. I notice that the draggable element is positioned in the corner of the canvas. I want to bring it back to the place I drop it.

I don't understand why the draggable element is not placed in the drop area if I don't use clone.

Comment: what do you mean by `clone`?

Comment: @DoanVanThang { helper: 'clone' }